Gesture onEnded doesn't fire in scroll view
I have a basic scroll view in SwiftUI that has stackable cards. The cards can be switched by swiping on them. Sometimes scrolls on the scroll view can be mistaken as drags on the draggable view. In this case the top card is dragged to somewhere else on the screen, but the onEnded doesn't fire and the card remains stuck in that position without returning back to the stack.
How can I fix the issue where scrolls on the scroll view are mistaken as drags on this sub view?
import SwiftUI

struct tetfqwe: View {
    @State var cards: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Color.blue.frame(height: 200)
            LazyVStack {
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(cards.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Color.red.frame(width: 120, height: 90).cornerRadius(15, corners: .allCorners)
                            .overlay(content: {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
                            })
                            .overlay(content: {
                                Text("\(index)")
                            })
                            .onTapGesture {
                                UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                            }
                            .offset(x: Double(((cards.count - 1) - index) * 3))
                            .offset(x: index == (cards.count - 1) ? offset.width : 0.0, y: index == (cards.count - 1) ? offset.height : 0.0)
                            .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture()
                                .onChanged({ value in
                                    if cards.count > 1 {
                                        offset = value.translation
                                    }
                                })
                                    .onEnded({ value in
                                        if cards.count > 1 {
                                            if abs(value.translation.width) > 45.0 {
                                                ended()
                                            } else {
                                                withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 0.3)){
                                                    offset = .zero
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            Color.orange.frame(height: 1000).padding(.top, 100)
            Color.green.frame(height: 1000)
            Color.gray.frame(height: 1000)
        }
    }
    func ended(){
        withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 0.3)){
            let element = cards.removeLast()
            cards.insert(element, at: 0)
            offset = .zero
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    tetfqwe()
}


try simultaneousGesture instead of  highPriorityGesture

@udi that didn't fix it, thanks for the idea though.

Do this on top side of your struct:
struct tetfqwe: View {

@State var cards: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
@State var offset: CGSize = .zero
@State var shouldScroll: Bool // add this to your code
        
var axes: Axis.Set { // add this to your code
    return shouldScroll ? .vertical : []
}

And towards the bottom, do this:
    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged({ value in
            
            shouldScroll = false // add this to your code

            if cards.count > 1 {
                offset = value.translation
            }
                 })
            .onEnded({ value in
 
                shouldScroll = true // add this to your code

                if cards.count > 1 {


This solution simply disables the scrollView while the drag is in action '.onChanged' and re-enables it when drag gesture 'onEnded' ends.

Thanks this should work. Maybe there's a simpler solution because my project has dozens of scroll views that can contain this subview. And also this cards subview has 3-4 parents before you get to the view with scroll view.

@AhmedZaidan This is a pretty simple solution. If your project has dozens of scrollviews that contain this then make another View that wraps this functionality. It's not like you need to copy paste it dozens of times.
